# Command substitution: splitting on newline but not space

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I know I can solve this problem several ways, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it using only bash built-ins, and if not, what is the most efficient way to do it.

I have a file with contents like

```
AAA
B C DDD
FOO BAR
```

by which I only mean it has several lines and each line may or may not have spaces.  I want to run a command like

```
cmd AAA "B C DDD" "FOO BAR"
```

If I use `cmd $(< file)` I get

```
cmd AAA B C DDD FOO BAR
```

and if I use `cmd "$(< file)"` I get

```
cmd "AAA B C DDD FOO BAR"
```

How do I get each line treated a exactly one parameter?

Comment: [question with +922 total votes: How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/918886/52074)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the canonical way to do this in `bash` is something like

```
unset args
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    args+=("$line") 
done < file

cmd "${args[@]}"
```

or, if your version of bash has `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t args < filename
cmd "${args[@]}"
```

The only difference I can find between the mapfile and the while-read loop versus the one-liner

```
(set -f; IFS=$'\n'; cmd $(<file))
```

is that the former will convert a blank line to an empty argument, while the one-liner will ignore a blank line.  In this case the one-liner behavior is what I'd prefer anyway, so double bonus on it being compact.

I would use `IFS=$'\n' cmd $(<file)` but it doesn't work, because `$(<file)` is interpreted to form the command line before `IFS=$'\n'` takes effect.

Though it doesn't work in my case, I've now learned that a lot of tools support terminating lines with `null (\000)` instead of `newline (\n)` which does make a lot of this easier when dealing with, say, file names, which are common sources of these situations:

```
find / -name '*.config' -print0 | xargs -0 md5
```

feeds a list of fully-qualified file names as arguments to md5 without any globbing or interpolating or whatever. That leads to the non-built-in solution

```
tr "\n" "\000" <file | xargs -0 cmd
```

although this, too, ignores empty lines, though it does capture lines that have only whitespace.

Comment: Using `cmd $(<file)` values without quoting (using the ability of bash to split words) is always a risky bet. If any line is `*` it will be expanded by the shell to a list of files.

Answer (score 31):

Portably:

```
set -f              # turn off globbing
IFS='
'                   # split at newlines only
cmd $(cat <file)
unset IFS
set +f
```

Or using a subshell to make the `IFS` and option changes local:

```
( set -f; IFS='
'; exec cmd $(cat <file) )
```

The shell performs field splitting and filename generation on the result of a variable or command substitution that is not in double quotes. So you need to turn off filename generation with `set -f`, and configure field splitting with `IFS` to make only newlines separate fields.

There's not much to be gained with bash or ksh constructs. You can make `IFS` local to a function, but not `set -f`.

In bash or ksh93, you can store the fields in an array, if you need to pass them to multiple commands. You need to control expansion at the time you build the array. Then `"${a[@]}"` expands to the elements of the array, one per word.

```
set -f; IFS=$'\n'
a=($(cat <file))
set +f; unset IFS
cmd "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with a temporary array.

#### Setup:

```
$ cat input
AAA
A B C
DE F
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

#### Fill the array:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; set -f; foo=($(<input))
```

#### Use the array:

```
$ for a in "${foo[@]}" ; do echo "--" "$a" "--" ; done
-- AAA --
-- A B C --
-- DE F --

$ ./t.sh "${foo[@]}"
AAA
A B C
DE F
```

Can't figure out a way of doing that without that temporary variable - unless the `IFS` change isn't important for `cmd`, in which case:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; set -f; cmd $(<input)
```

should do it.

Comment: `IFS` always gets me confused.  `IFS=$'\n' cmd $(<input)` doesn't work.  `IFS=$'\n'; cmd $(<input); unset IFS` does work. Why?  I guess I'll use `(IFS=$'\n'; cmd $(<input))`

Comment: @OldPro `IFS=$'\n' cmd $(<input)` doesn't work because it only sets `IFS` in the environment of `cmd`. `$(<input)` is expanded to form the command, before the assignment to `IFS` is performed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the bash built-in `mapfile` to read the file into an array

```
mapfile -t foo < filename
cmd "${foo[@]}"
```

or, untested, `xargs` might do it

```
xargs cmd < filename
```

Comment: From the mapfile documentation: "mapfile isn't a common or portable shell feature".  And indeed is it not supported on my system.  `xargs` doesn't help, either.

Comment: You would need `xargs -d` or `xargs -L`

Comment: @James, no, I don't have a `-d` option and `xargs -L 1` runs the command once per line but still splits args on whitespace.

Comment: @OldPro, well you did ask for "a way to do it using only bash built-ins" instead of "a common or portable shell feature". If your version of bash is too old, can you update it?

Comment: `mapfile` is very handy for me, as it grabs blank lines as array items, which the `IFS` method does not do. `IFS` treats contiguous newlines as a single delimiter... Thanks for presenting it, as I wasn't aware of the command (though, based on the OP's input data and the expected command line, it seems he actually wants to ignore blank lines).

Comment: I introduced the `-d` option in 2005, your version of `xargs` must be quite old.   You're right about `-L`; I should have typed `-I{}` (but even that does unexpected things with trailing spaces, which is one of the reasons `-d` exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
old=$IFS
IFS='  #newline
'
array=`cat Submissions` #input the text in this variable
for ...  #use parts of variable in the for loop
... 
done
IFS=$old
```

Best way I could find. Just Works.

Comment: And why does it work if you set `IFS` to space, but the question is to **not** split on space?

Answer (score 0):

## File

The most basic loop (portable) to split a file on newlines is:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r line; do            # get one line (\n) at a time.
    set -- "$@" "$line"           # store in the list of positional arguments.
done <infile                      # read from a file called infile.
printf '<%s>' "$@" ; echo         # print the results.
```

Which will print:

```
$ ./script
<AAA><A B C><DE F>
```

Yes, with default IFS=<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>newline</kbd>.

**Why it works**

- IFS will be used by the shell to split the input into **several** variables. As there is only **one** variable, no splitting is perform by the shell. So, no change of `IFS` needed.
- Yes, leading and trailing spaces/tabs are being removed, but it doesn't seem to be a problem in this case.
- No, no **globbing** is done as no expansion is **unquoted**. So, no `set -f` needed.
- The only array used (or needed) is the array-like positional parameters.
- The `-r` (raw) option is to avoid the removal of most backslash.

That will **not** work if splitting and/or globbing is needed. In such cases a more complex structure is needed.

If you need (still portable) to:

- Avoid removal of leading and trailing spaces/tabs, use: `IFS= read -r line`
- Split line to vars on some character, use: `IFS=':' read -r a b c`.

Split the **file** on some other character (not portable, works with ksh, bash, zsh):

```
IFS=':' read -d '+' -r a b c
```

## Expansion

Of course, the title of your question is about spliting a command execution on newlines avoiding the split on spaces.

The only way to get splitting from the shell is to leave an expansion without quotes:

```
echo $(< file)
```

That is controlled by the value of IFS, and, on unquoted expansions, globbing is also applied. To mkae that work, you need:

- Set IFS to new line **only**, to get splitting on newline only.
- Unset the globbing shell option `set +f`:

  set +f
  IFS='
  '
  cmd $(< file)

Of course, that change the value of IFS and of globbing for the rest of the script.